# How to make UWP WebView2 transparent?

Tags: uwp, webview2

I am trying to find a way to make the UWP WebView2 transparent to use it in game bar widget that supports full transparency.

I tried different ways I found on the Internet but nothing worked. The background stays white.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winui2#setting-transparency), it is recommended to use `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` to set the transparency.

> **Setting DefaultBackgroundColor**
>
> On WinUI 2, the DefaultBackgroundColor property is not exposed
> directly. You can set the default background color by setting an
> environment variable, as follows:
>
> ```
> Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBVIEW2_DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR","FF000000");
> ```
>
> **Setting transparency**
>
> On WinUI 2, transparency is achieved by setting the color to **00FFFFFF**.
>
> This environment variable must be set prior to CoreWebView2 creation,
> which occurs when the WebView2.Source property is initially set or the
> `WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async` method is initially called.

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBVIEW2_DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR", "00FFFFFF");
await webView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
```